# Objective C implementation of Swift's if-let

Tags: objective-c, macros

This [Objective-]C-preprocessor macro currently handles single-variable if-let-not-nil and if-let-is-type, but doesn't handle multiple simultaneous tests and doesn't handle `where` clauses.

I prefer functions to macros, but I don't see any way to pass a local variable *name* to a function such that it would create a code block which can use that *name* internally when being compiled. Is there any way to make this a function?

This does *not* handle commas in code block: this can be worked around with `()` brackets, e.g.
     `foo = @[1, 2];`
         becomes
     `foo = (@[1, 2]);`, but I'd prefer something that doesn't surprise anyone using the macro, especially as the compiler error when commas are not wrapped in brackets is unhelpful.

```
#define IF_LET(tempType, temp, optional, code) \
if ((optional)!=nil && [optional isKindOfClass:tempType.class]) { \
    tempType *temp = (tempType*)optional;\
    {code}\
}
```

example usage:

```
for (SKNode *node in touchedNodes) {
    IF_LET(Tile, tile, node, {
        // Tile (capital) is one of my own classes
        // tile (lowercase) is defined at this point by the macro and only available within this code block
        SKAction *scale = [SKAction scaleBy: 1.2 duration: 0.15];
        SKAction *action = ([SKAction sequence:@[scale, scale.reversedAction]]);
        [tile runAction:action];
    })
}

SKLabelNode *t = nil;
IF_LET(SKLabelNode, temp, t, {
    // doesn't run: t was nil
})

t = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:@"some text"];
IF_LET(NSObject, temp, t, {
    // this block runs, letting you do stuff with the local scope variable
    // NSObject *temp = (NSObject*)t;
}) else {
    // else block available for use, but
    // this one doesn't run because t is not nil and is a kind of NSObject
}

IF_LET(NSArray, temp, t, {
    // doesn't run, t is of wrong type
})
```

How can I improve this macro?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be: *Don't do it.* The main disadvantages 
(in my opinion) are:

- As you noticed, commas inside the macro argument are not handled,
  leading to "strange" error messages:

  ```
  for (SKNode *node in touchedNodes) {
      IF_LET(Tile, tile, node, { 
          // Use of undeclared identifier 'IF_LET'
          SKAction *scale = [SKAction scaleBy: 1.2 duration: 0.15];
          SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[scale, scale.reversedAction]];
          // Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
          [tile runAction:action];
      })
  }
  ```

  It is not obvious how this must be fixed, and enclosing all Objective-C
  message calls feels unnatural.
- Macros are not known to the debugger. As a consequence, you cannot
  set a breakpoint at a certain line inside the block – the debugger will
  stop at the end of the block instead.
- For the same reason you cannot single-step through the block statements.

Some of your intended applications have alternatives in pure
Objective-C, which are (almost) as good.

*Example 1:* Your code

```
for (SKNode *node in touchedNodes) {
    IF_LET(Tile, tile, node, {
        SKAction *scale = [SKAction scaleBy: 1.2 duration: 0.15];
        SKAction *action = ([SKAction sequence:@[scale, scale.reversedAction]]);
        [tile runAction:action];
    })
}
```

can be replaced by

```
for (Tile *tile in touchedNodes) {
    if ([tile isKindOfClass:Tile.class]) {
        SKAction *scale = [SKAction scaleBy: 1.2 duration: 0.15];
        SKAction *action = ([SKAction sequence:@[scale, scale.reversedAction]]);
        [tile runAction:action];
    }
}
```

The fast-enumeration `for` statement does not care how about the
type of the loop variable, you only have to verify its class before
accessing it.

*Example 2:* Your code

```
SKLabelNode *t = nil;
IF_LET(SKLabelNode, temp, t, {
    // doesn't run: t was nil
    [temp setText:@"text"];
})
```

can be replaced by (the even shorter)

```
SKLabelNode *t = nil;
[t setText:@"text"];
```

because sending Objective-C message to `nil` is a no-op.

*Example 3:* Your code

```
t = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:@"some text"];
IF_LET(NSObject, temp, t, {
    // this block runs, letting you do stuff with the local scope variable
    // NSObject *temp = (NSObject*)t;
}) else {
    // else block available for use, but
    // this one doesn't run because t is not nil and is a kind of NSObject
}
```

is equivalent to

```
t = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:@"some text"];
if (t != nil) {
    // Local scope for if-case
} else {
    // Local scope for else-case
}
```